# angular.js:117 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im working on my first angular.js but my application got an error it keeps on looping. I think the error is in my ng-route configuration but i cant figure it how to solve it.

myapp.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

 app.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.

            when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'index.html',
              controller: 'mainController'

            }).

            when('/main', {
               templateUrl: 'main.html',
               controller: 'mainController'
            }).

            when('/register', {
               templateUrl: 'register.html',
               controller: 'authController'
            }).

            when('/update', {
               templateUrl: 'update.html',
               controller: 'authController'
            }).

            otherwise({
               redirectTo: '/'
            });
});


app.controller('mainController', function($scope){

});

app.controller('authController', function($scope){


  $scope.update = function(){

  };

  $scope.register = function(){

  };
});
```

index.html

```
        <div ng-view> </div>
```

Stack Error.

```
angular.js:117 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
        at ja (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:80:376)
        at n (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:66:28)
        at g (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:58:305)
        at g (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:58:322)
        at g (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:58:322)
        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:57:455

        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular-route.js:866:15
        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:57:445
        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:62:281
        at update (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular-route.js:839:13)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:117(anonymous function) @ angular.js:89ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820
    11angular.js:117 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
        at Object.error (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:117:212)
        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:89:505
        at ja (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:80:372)
        at n (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:66:28)
        at g (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:58:305)
        at g (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:58:322)
        at g (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:58:322)
        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:57:455
        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular-route.js:866:15
        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:57:445(anonymous function) @ angular.js:117(anonymous function) @ angular.js:89ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820
    angular.js:117 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
        at Object.error (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:117:212)
        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:89:505
        at ja (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:80:372)
        at n (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:66:28)
        at g (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:58:305)
        at g (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:58:322)
        at g (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:58:322)
        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:57:455
        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular-route.js:866:15
        at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:57:445 <!-- ngView:  -->(anonymous function) @ angular.js:117(anonymous function) @ angular.js:89ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820ja @ angular.js:80n @ angular.js:66g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58g @ angular.js:58(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:866(anonymous function) @ angular.js:57(anonymous function) @ angular.js:62update @ angular-route.js:839(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:820
    10angular.js:117 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
        at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
        at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
        at String.replace (native)
        at cb (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:29:523)
        at xa (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:87:188)
        at x (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:60:1)
        at s (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:58:402)
        at s (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:59:55)
        at s (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:59:55)
        at s (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:59:55) <!-- ngView:  -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the following code:

```
        when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'index.html',
          controller: 'mainController'

        }).
```

And the `index.html` has `<div ng-view> </div>`. So the angularjs tries to replace ng-view with `index.html` and this goes on and on like a infinite recursion.

What you can do is add `home.html`

```
 <div>Home page</div>
```

and replace the routing as:

```
    when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'mainController'

    }).
```

Comment: I replace the index.html but when i click to another link i got this error  404 not found

Comment: Don't replace index.html. You need bothe index.html & home.html. index.html is your main file.